# Call external php file in html not working

Tags: php, html

I have an html file called `index.html` where I want to add external php file to run it as my "header". I cut the code which contains logo and navigation menu and added it to a file named `header.php`.

I've used this code: `<?php include 'header.php';?>` after my `<body id="page1">` div but what loads is the rest of the pages without the navigation menu that is on `header.php`. I've also tried using ajax as someone else mentioned in another post but this doesn't work too.

[Code before changes](http://pastebin.com/5wqZpfZM)

[Code after changes](http://pastebin.com/yPBBnLR6)

Comment: code added to first message

Answer (score 1):

just rename index.html to index.php

Comment: Thanks but I've done it this way: 
Editing `.htaccess` in root folder of web site and adding `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm` DID the job as I wanted it. Now everything is showing properly without the need to rename `index.html` to `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: you are trying to include a PHP file in an HTML file. An HTML file cannot process a PHP file. Rename your `index.html` file to `index.php'. And then view it using the`http://`protocol rather than the`file://` protocol.

Comment: I'm doing the changes on server and not locally and 2nd I have links coming to html which I don't want to change and for SEO reasons.

Comment: Sorry. But only a PHP file can understand the `<?php ?>` tags and process the `include` PHP directive.

Comment: This code `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .php .htm` inside .htaccess doesn't do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Editing `.htaccess` in root folder of web site and adding `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm` DID the job as I wanted it. Now everything is showing properly without the need to rename `index.html` to `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

If renaming the index.html file is not an option, you can load the php file with a ajax request on page load. And prepend the response to the body tag.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use JQuery+Ajax Script without changing any parameters to server, to execute .php in .html file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'cleardata.php'
    });
});
</script>
```